# Drag N' Drop 100+ Files Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've been searching for an answer on the internet and can't seem to get a definitive one. I've been having an issue with getting a .bat file to accept more than 80 files at once for conversion and file look up with a batch script that links to a python script.

Here is an example of what I'm doing, it's easy enough...

```
@ECHO OFF
python "C:\myDirectory\Conversion_and_Excel_Extractor.py" %*
PAUSE
```

Again, this seems to work with 80 files drag and dropped unto the batch script but doesn't seem to work with more than that. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: there is a restriction on how many chars batch can handle. If your parameter(s) string (all those file names) is above that limit, it is cut.

Comment: What about putting them in a directory and having over the directory (or some search pattern) instead?

Comment: @Stephan, I wasn't aware of that. Fairly new to batch scripting, so cheers for that information! I have a large amount of files with which have names that are between 30 and 90 characters long... Is there a way I can, perhaps, take the first 15 of the name and limit it that way to allot a higher limit of files?

Comment: @FlorianStraub, they are located in their own directory. I would prefer to drag the entire set of files, or the entire directory, into my batch file and iterate over the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> they are located in their own directory. I would prefer to drag the
>   entire set of files, or the entire directory, into my batch file and
>   iterate over the files

that's possible:

drag the folder to your batch file and use

```
python "C:\myDirectory\Conversion_and_Excel_Extractor.py" "%~1\*"
```

As an alternative you could drag *any one* of the files to the batch file and use `%~dp1` to get the folder and

```
python "C:\myDirectory\Conversion_and_Excel_Extractor.py" "%~dp1\*"
```

to process all files in this directory.

Comment: that was exactly my intention :)

Comment: It's nearly perfect, but I think I can figure the rest out from here. It only provides the file name, yet I still need to get the path. Shouldn't be too difficult! I appreciate the help.